# How do I split an array and read back the results?

Tags: java

When I read in a string, such as "Georgia Southern(Sun Belt)|9|-1|-1|-1|-1|0|0|1" and then split the string as per the code below, I am unable to successfully print out a split section from the array. Instead, only one letter gets printed out. With the code below my output is 'G' instead of "Georgia Southern(Sun Belt)".

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class Schedule
{
   public static void main (String args[])throws IOException
   {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("Footballteams.txt"));
      Set<Football>teams=new TreeSet<Football>();
      String x=sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println(x);
      String[]a=x.split("|",9);
      System.out.println(a[1]);     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String split takes a regular expression as the first parameter. Pipe ("|") is matched to the OR operator, so you have to delimit it thusly split("\\|",9)

Answer (score 0):

You *are* printing the array element correctly. The array element is in fact "G".

Why? Because `split` expects a regular expression as the argument. In a regular expression `a|b` means "match `a` or `b`", so `|` by itself means "match the empty string or the empty string", so it matches the empty string. That causes `split` to split at every possible point (i.e. between every pair of characters).

To match an actual `|`, use `x.split("\\|", 9)` instead of `x.split("|", 9)`.